# 403 -- Forbidden:URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb0_notop.h5

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create a base model with EfficientNetB0 in jupyter Notebook but I see an error to
**Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb0_notop.h5**
my problem is that I don't know where to put the downloaded file.

Comment: Your IP is forbidden to access the URL. You may use a VPN.

Comment: You’re trying to open in your web browser is a resource that you’re not allowed to access. Use different internet connectivity or VPN. Thanks!